# Role inheritance with shared groups

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus, gitlab-ce

A self-hosted GitLab Instance (Community Edition 12.10.8) is considered.
Let's assume the following Group setup:

- Group

  - Subgroup 1
  - Subgroup 1.1 (Admins)
  - Subgroup 1.2

    - Project A

Now, The Subgroup 1.1 is invited to Subgroup 1 with the role **Owner**.
The idea is that the user members in Subgroup 1.1 act as administrators for the Subgroup 1 and all further subgroups.

With this setup, the users from Subgroup 1.1 ("Admins") can access e.g the Subgroup 1.2 and its Project A. This was not the case before the group was added, i.e. the user have become members! However, I observe that:

- The added users or the added group does not show up in the members list of Subgroup 1.2.
- Even though the "Admins" should now be **Owner** of Subgroup 1.2 and Project A due to inheritance, they cannot delete Project A.

If I alternatively add a user as **Owner** to the Subgroup 1, he shows up as owner in Subgroup 1.2 and he can delete Project A.

Why does it make a difference if a user is directly added or added via a group?

In the [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/group/#sharing-a-group-with-another-group) it says:

> Similarly to sharing a project with a group, you can share a group with another group to give direct group members access to the shared
>   group. This is not valid for inherited members.
>
> To share a given group, for example, ‘Frontend’ with another group,
>   for example, ‘Engineering’:
>
> 1. Navigate to your ‘Frontend’ group page and use the left navigation menu to go to your group Members.
> 2. Select the Invite group tab.
> 3. Add ‘Engineering’ with the maximum access level of your choice.
> 4. Click Invite.
>
> All the members of the ‘Engineering’ group will have been added to
>   ‘Frontend’.

To me, this sounds like the added group members have identical function as directly added users.
Only the sentence "*This is not valid for inherited members.*" might be the explanation, but I think I need further explanation on this.

Has anybody understood the logic behind this?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: So I found an open issue regarding the problem that shared group members are not listed: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219230/   (still doesn't explain why the members have not full owner privileges)

Comment: And I also found the permission issue described here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213546

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing the [GitLab issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues),  I come to the conclusion that both mentioned problems are (known) bugs and are discussed in issues at GitLab:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/213546
- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219230

I guess this is as good as we come right now . Hopefully, both issues are solved soon.